# How to create a custom camera preview view with UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

Sorry if this question is somewhat broad, but I have been searching for hours without a great solution that fits my specific needs for this problem.

For some background information, the iOS app that I am working on calls for a camera overlay (a png of a mask image) where the user has the ability to place their face in and capture a photo with the mask overlay on top of it. The camera is initially set to the front because the main purpose is to have somewhat of a selfie functionality. After tapping the default capture button, the camera preview image gets mirrored or reversed.

Everything looks great before the photo is captured into camera preview view; however, after it is captured, it gets mirrored or reversed. For example, if I am holding up my left hand while setting up to capture the picture, and I capture that image, the camera preview will look like I am holding up my right hand.

During my research, I have found a couple of solutions that do not exactly fit my needs or fully explain how I could go about solving the problem. My project is exclusively written in Swift, and the management wants to keep it this way at all costs if possible. Below, I will list the solutions that I found:

1. This project is essentially everything that I need; however, it is written in Objective-C: https://github.com/lucasecf/LEMirroredImagePicker
2. All of the other solutions that I came upon were either to create a custom camera in its entirety (Capture, Cancel, Use Photo, Retake, Camera Preview, etc.) or to use AVFoundation (Never worked with this and there are not many examples in Swift).

Here is the only code that I have so far pertaining to working with UIImagePickerController:

```
var picker = UIImagePickerController()

@IBAction func shootPhoto(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModes(for: .front) != nil {
        picker = UIImagePickerController() //make a clean controller
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        picker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
        picker.cameraDevice = .front
        picker.showsCameraControls = true

        //customView stuff
        let customViewController = CustomOverlayViewController(
            nibName:"CustomOverlayViewController",
            bundle: nil)
        let customView:CustomOverlayView = customViewController.view as! CustomOverlayView
        customView.frame = self.picker.view.frame

        picker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(picker,animated: true,completion: {
            self.picker.cameraOverlayView = customView
        })
    } else { //no camera found -- alert the user.
        let alertVC = UIAlertController(
            title: "No Camera",
            message: "Sorry, this device has no camera",
            preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(
            title: "OK",
            style:.default,
            handler: nil)
        alertVC.addAction(okAction)
        present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

So, if someone can either provide a full-fledged solution or guide me somehow (although, I think I have seen everything on the internet already) that would awesome!

Comment: This is a really common question, it is the default behavior of the front-facing camera to show the mirrored image.  Just flip the captured image horizontally to get your desired output

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will I need to create a custom camera preview and set the captured image to this? I am unsure how to grab the captured image and make the required modification to it.

Comment: I think theres a delegate method for UIImagePickerController for when the camera has captured a picture so you can get the UIImage there... and then you could add an overlay to show the flipped UIImage